# Position keyframes do not make a straight path

Tags: path, animation, adobe-after-effects

I have made a square and inserted a position keyframe and holding shift I drag to right and got a straight path. When I want to raise up or make an "L" shape by holding shift it does not make a straight line this time. It creates a curved shape instead.

How can I have a straight line path? Which key do I have to press to get a straight line?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After Effects defaults spacial interpolation (such as position keyframes) to "Auto Bezier", which tries to smooth the movement for you.

You can either adjust the bezier handles yourself, or you can right click the keyframes themselves in the timeline and select *Keyframe Interpolation...* to change the spacial interpolation ("Linear" will give you straight paths):

[image]

[image]

You can also change the default to linear by going to *Preferences → General* and checking *Default Spatial Interpolation To Linear*.

You can read more about keyframe interpolation here:

- [After Effects User Guide – About spatial and temporal keyframe interpolation](https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/after-effects/using/keyframe-interpolation.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can see in your screen cap the small non-anchor "handles" which show up tangent to the curves you're pulling out: if you grab each one of those on each side of the anchor at the corner and move it TO the anchor point at the corner, you will turn the curve into a hard corner.